# segue when clicking on a uicollectionview cell inside a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, delegates

I have the following situation:

ExploreViewController is a table view controller with CategoryTableViewCell (child class of UITableViewCell)

The CategoryTableViewCell has a CollectionView with UICollectionViewCells.

When a user clicks on a UICollectionViewCell, I would like to segue ExploreViewController to BookListViewController based on the uICollectionViewCell data. Each UICollectionViewCell stands for a separated category.

How can I do this using swift? I tried using delegate protocol, but when I call performSegue inside the delegate function inside the ExploreViewController, I get an error.

In CategoryTableViewCell

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("test12")
        self.delegate?.didSelectInEmbeddedCollection()
    }
}

protocol CategoryTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didSelectInEmbeddedCollection()
}
```

In ExploreViewController

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print("test14")
        if segue.identifier == "toBookListFeatured",
            let destination = segue.destination as? BookListViewController,
            let selectedIndexPath = self.tableViewFeaturedCats.indexPathForSelectedRow,
            let selectedCell = self.self.tableViewFeaturedCats.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath) as? CategoryTableViewCell
        {
            let collectionView = selectedCell.collectionView
            let indexPathC = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first
            let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPathC!) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell
            destination.data = cell!.label.text
        } else {
            // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
            // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
            let dc = segue.destination as! BookListViewController
            dc.data = self.tableRowData["name"] as! String;
            dc.searchByCategory = true
        }
    }

}
extension ExploreViewController: CategoryTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didSelectInEmbeddedCollection() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toBookListFeatured", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: What error? Which error? Where is your code block?

Comment: I added code. See above

Comment: Please add your error line.

Comment: I didn't get an error line just a sigart

Comment: sigart means  failure to access something which is nil or doesn't exist, is `BookListViewController` is in ObjC?

Comment: Your code has the error `let selectedCell = self.self.tableViewFeaturedCats.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath) as? CategoryTableViewCell`, please compile to make sure the code is correct.